# Duplicate result(recordset&recordsets) appears when using GET Method

Tags: sql-server, node.js

i have a node service to get all students and it retrieves the students correct but with duplicate data as following :

```
{
"recordsets": [
    [
        {
            "UID": 5,
            "FName": "Ahmed",
            "LName": "Fawzy",
            "Birthdate": "1995-07-10T00:00:00.000Z",
            "CityID": 1,
            "UserTypeID": 2
        }
    ]
],
"recordset": [
    {
        "UID": 6,
        "FName": "Mohammed",
        "LName": "Hassan",
        "Birthdate": "1995-06-14T00:00:00.000Z",
        "CityID": 4,
        "UserTypeID": 2
    }
],
"output": {},
"rowsAffected": [
    3
]
}
```

i just want to retrieve the recordset,and now i don't want to see these duplicated data and also the rows affected
so here are my codes:

students.js

```
var db = require("../Core/DB");
exports.getList = function(req,res){
  db.executeSql('select * from [Users] where UserTypeID =2 ',function(data,err){
if(err){
    res.writeHead(500,"Internal error occured!!!",{"Content-Type":"text/html"});
    res.write("<html><head><title>500</title></head><body>500:Internal error details: "+err+"</body></html>");
}
else{
    res.writeHead(200,{"Content-Type":"application/json"});
    res.write(JSON.stringify(data));
}
res.end();
  });  
};
```

db.js

```
var sqlDb = require("mssql");
var settings = require("../settings");


exports.executeSql = function (sql, callback)
{
var conn = new sqlDb.ConnectionPool(settings.dbConfig);
conn.connect()
.then(function(){
    var req = new sqlDb.Request(conn);
    req.query(sql)
    .then(function(recordset){
        callback(recordset);
    })
    .catch(function(err){
        console.log(err);
        callback(null,err);
    });
})
.catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
    callback(null,err);
});
};
```

and here is how i call the getlist() function :

```
var http = require("http");
var student = require("../controllers/Students");
var settings = require("../settings");

http.createServer(function(req,res){
switch(req.method){
    case "GET":
    if(req.url === "/")
    {
        res.end();
    }
    else if (req.url === "/students")
    {
        student.getList(req,res);
    }
    break;
```

Comment: it was solved by changing  res.write(JSON.stringify(data)); into  res.write(JSON.stringify(data.recordsets)); thanks to @JithinScaria

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try changing below line in `students.js`

`res.write(JSON.stringify(data));`

to

`res.write(JSON.stringify(data.recordsets));`

Comment: it throws an error TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The first argument must be one of type string or Buffer

Comment: try `res.write(data[0]);` - without json conversion

Comment: `res.write(JSON.stringify(data.recordsets));`

Comment: that should be your first answer :D it was solved with exactly what i want :D thanks for your time and support

Comment: could you please clarify what was the problem ? @JithinScaria

Comment: Sure, res.write need to have a string or buffer, but when we did data[0] it is trying to send an array ,thats the reason we got the error. . But when i revisited your question, i understood it was my bad, i could have used the last one as it directly fetches data we need.